# Difficulty accessing table data with beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

This is slightly embarassing, but I'm trying to scrape some user scores off of myanimelist and I've run into trouble.

When I look at the html, it looks to me like they're under an "a" tag with "class="link"". But when I try to use the find or find_all method it just gives me garbage.

I also tried just getting the table "table class="list-table"." This actually gets me the information I want but it's under a data-items thing that I don't know how to access.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page_link = 'https://myanimelist.net/animelist/PankiePea?status=7' #my profile as an example
page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=10)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.text, "html.parser")

scores = soup.find_all('a','link')
```

data-items thing

```
[<table class="list-table" data-items='[{"status":1,"score":6,"tags":"","is_rewatching":0,"num_watched_episodes":12,"anime_title":"One Punch Man 2nd Season","anime_num_episodes":12,"anime_airing_status":2,"anime_id"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `json.loads` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#json.loads)) to load the data in the `data-items` attribute:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://myanimelist.net/animelist/PankiePea?status=7'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

data = json.loads( soup.select_one('.list-table[data-items]')['data-items'] )   # load data from `data-items` attribute

# print data to the screen
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
[
    {
        "status": 1,
        "score": 6,
        "tags": "",
        "is_rewatching": 0,
        "num_watched_episodes": 12,
        "anime_title": "One Punch Man 2nd Season",
        "anime_num_episodes": 12,
        "anime_airing_status": 2,
        "anime_id": 34134,
        "anime_studios": null,
        "anime_licensors": null,
        "anime_season": null,
        "has_episode_video": true,
        "has_promotion_video": true,
        "has_video": true,
        "video_url": "/anime/34134/One_Punch_Man_2nd_Season/video",
        "anime_url": "/anime/34134/One_Punch_Man_2nd_Season",
        "anime_image_path": "https://cdn.myanimelist.net/r/96x136/images/anime/1805/99571.jpg?s=76893d6eb26f8add6731bcfa56f243ec",
        "is_added_to_list": false,
        "anime_media_type_string": "TV",
        "anime_mpaa_rating_string": "R",
        "start_date_string": null,
        "finish_date_string": null,
        "anime_start_date_string": "04-10-19",
        "anime_end_date_string": "07-03-19",
        "days_string": null,
        "storage_string": "",
        "priority_string": "Low"
    },
    {
        "status": 2,

... and so on.
```

EDIT: To locate tag with `data-items` attribute we use CSS selector `.list-table[data-items]` - select tag with class `list-table` that contains `data-items` attribute.